# Couldn't find org.apache.thrift7.TBase class

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, thrift, thrift-protocol

I am getting error while executing the topology using the following maven command :

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.test.newpackage.TopologyMain" -Dexec.args="resource/words.txt"
```

If i try using following command :

```
java -cp ./target/wordcount-0.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/storm-0.8.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/conf/storm.yaml com.test.newpackage.TopologyMain resource/words.txt
```

It neither gives error nor output. Even after i submit the topology to storm using :

```
storm jar StormEclipse.jar com.test.newpackage.TopologyMain /resource/words.txt
```

This topology doesn't list on the ui(localhost:8080).

```
 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'exec'.
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building Unnamed - com.test.newpackage:wordcount:jar:0.0.1
    [INFO]    task-segment: [exec:java]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Preparing exec:java
    [INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
    [INFO] [exec:java {execution: default-cli}]
    [WARNING] 
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/thrift7/TBase
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:788)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:447)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder.initCommon(TopologyBuilder.java:215)
        at backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder.setSpout(TopologyBuilder.java:178)
        at backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder.setSpout(TopologyBuilder.java:164)
        at com.test.newpackage.TopologyMain.main(TopologyMain.java:12)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.thrift7.TBase
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 21 more
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] An exception occured while executing the Java class. null

    org.apache.thrift7.TBase
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 1 second
    [INFO] Finished at: Mon Jul 22 18:55:23 IST 2013
    [INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [org.apache.thrift7.TBase vs org.apache.thrift.TBase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806331/org-apache-thrift7-tbase-vs-org-apache-thrift-tbase)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the scope of the storm dependency. The example [pom.xml](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Maven) suggested in storm wiki sets the scope to test. So when you execute with maven, It will fail to resolve storm dependencies.

Remove the test scope, if you want to run it through maven