# org.apache.thrift7.TBase vs org.apache.thrift.TBase

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, thrift, thrift-protocol

I am not being able to find any jar which contain this kind of package. Can, anyone tell me in which libthrift [Link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/l/Downloadlibthrift080jar.htm) jar i can find this class and package. I couldn't find any jar containing this package. Everytime i execute my java file it throw following expection:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/thrift7/TBase
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder.initCommon(TopologyBuilder.java:215)
    at backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder.setSpout(TopologyBuilder.java:178)
    at backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder.setSpout(TopologyBuilder.java:164)
    at com.test.newpackage.TopologyMain.main(TopologyMain.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.thrift7.TBase
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [searching Central](http://search.maven.org/) when you're looking for a class. [fc:"org.apache.thrift.TBase"](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|fc%3A%22org.apache.thrift.TBase%22) suggests [org.apache.thrift:libthrift:0.9.0](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.thrift|libthrift|0.9.0|pom).

For `libthrift7`, see the [instructions on the Storm wiki](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Maven): use the http://clojars.org/repo repository and depend directly on `storm:storm`. [`storm:libthrift7`](http://clojars.org/repo/storm/libthrift7/) will be brought in transitively.

Comment: I added `org.apache.thrift` dependency.....But still getting the same error due to missing *org.apache.thrift7.TBase* package. But, when i use `java -cp ./target/wordcount-0.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/storm-0.8.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/conf/storm.yaml com.test.newpackage.TopologyMain resource/words.txt` command it doesn't give me any error nor gives me output.

Comment: See [How can I create an executable jar with dependencies using Maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Answer (score 2):

Did you include `org.apache.thrift` in the maven dependencies.? If not please include:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
  <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I added this in pom.xml. But, the point is it has the `org.apache.thrift` package NOT `org.apache.thrift7` mind the 7 at the end. So, not able to resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

please include following:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/storm/libthrift7 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>libthrift7</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.0-2</version>
</dependency>
```